# Python pint module with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pint

The python pint module implements physical quantities. I would like to use it together with multiprocessing. However, I don't know how to handle creating a UnitRegistry in the new process. If I do the intuitive:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from pint import UnitRegistry, set_application_registry

ureg = UnitRegistry()
set_application_registry(ureg)
Q = ureg.Quantity


def f(one, two):
    print(one / two)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=(Q(50, 'ms'), Q(50, 'ns')))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Then I get an the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\pmaunz\PyCharmProjects\IonControl34\tests\pintmultiprocessing.py", line 12, in f
    print(one / two)
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pint\quantity.py", line 738, in __truediv__
    return self._mul_div(other, operator.truediv)
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pint\quantity.py", line 675, in _mul_div
    offset_units_self = self._get_non_multiplicative_units()
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pint\quantity.py", line 1312, in _get_non_multiplicative_units
    offset_units = [unit for unit in self._units.keys()
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pint\quantity.py", line 1313, in <listcomp>
    if not self._REGISTRY._units[unit].is_multiplicative]
KeyError: 'millisecond'
```

Which I assume originates from the lack of initializing the UnitRegistry on the child process before unpickling the arguments. (Initializing the UnitRegistry in the function f does not work, as the variables have already been unpickled).

How would I go about sending a pint Quantity to a child process?

Edit after Tim Peter's answer:

The problem is *not* tied to multiprocessing. Simply pickling quantities

```
from pint import UnitRegistry, set_application_registry
import pickle
ureg = UnitRegistry()
set_application_registry(ureg)
Q = ureg.Quantity
with open("pint.pkl", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(Q(50, 'ms'), f)
    pickle.dump(Q(50, 'ns'), f)
```

and then unpickling in a *new* script leads to the same problem:

```
from pint import UnitRegistry, set_application_registry 
import pickle
ureg = UnitRegistry()
set_application_registry(ureg)
Q = ureg.Quantity
with open("pint.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    t1 = pickle.load(f)
    t2 = pickle.load(f)

print(t1 / t2)
```

results in the same exception. As Tim points out, it is sufficient to add a line `Q(50, 'ns'); Q(50, 'ms')` before unpickling. When digging into the source code for pint, upon creation of a quantity with unit `ms` this unit is added to an internal registry. Pickling uses a `UnitContainer` instance to save the units. When creating a Quantity via unpickling the unit is *not* added to the registry.

A simple fix (in pint source code) is to change the function `Quantity.__reduce__` to return a string.

```
diff --git a/pint/quantity.py b/pint/quantity.py
index 3f30a25..695866a 100644
--- a/pint/quantity.py
+++ b/pint/quantity.py
@@ -57,7 +57,7 @@ class _Quantity(SharedRegistryObject):

     def __reduce__(self):
         from . import _build_quantity
-        return _build_quantity, (self.magnitude, self._units)
+        return _build_quantity, (self.magnitude, str(self._units))

     def __new__(cls, value, units=None):
         if units is None:
```

I have opened an issue on pint's github site.

Comment: Bravo!  That all makes great sense.  I'm only surprised that nobody bumped into this before - pickling in one process and unpickling in another is the _usual_ way pickles are used (even in the absence of `multiprocessing`)!

Answer (score 3):

I never used `pint` before, but this looked interesting ;-)  First thing I noted is that I have no problem if I stick to units explicitly listed by this line:

```
print(dir(ureg.sys.mks))
```

For example, "hour" and "second" are both in the output of that, and your program runs fine if the `Process` line is changed to:

```
p = Process(target=f, args=(Q(50, 'hour'), Q(50, 'second')))
```

You're on Windows, so `multiprocessing` is using the "spawn" method:  the entire program is imported fresh by the worker process, so in particular the:

```
ureg = UnitRegistry()
set_application_registry(ureg)
Q = ureg.Quantity
```

lines were executed in the worker process too.  So the unit registry *is* initialized in the worker, but it's not the same (identical) registry used in the main program - no memory is shared between processes.

To get much deeper we really need an expert in how `pint` is implemented.  My guess is that for units "made up" (not in the output produced by the `dir()` line above) by parsing strings, new stuff is added to the registry at some level, which is needed later to reconstruct the values.  "ns" and "ms" are of this nature:  they are *not* in the `dir()` output.

Your program works fine as-is *if* I add a line like this immediately after your `Q=ureg.Quantity` line:

```
Q(1, 'ms'); Q(1, 'ns')
```

That was a shot in the dark (an "educated guess") that worked:  it just forced the worker process to parse the same "made up" units used in the main process, to try to force *its* unit registry into a similar state.

I hope there's a cleaner way to get it to work, but can't help more.  I'd ask the `pint` authors about it.

Comment: On unix like systems it is sufficient now (pint-0.16.1) to simply call set_application_registry.